# Post json data using fetch api failed

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fetch-api

Am new in javascript , and am trying to **POST** data with an API endpoint but data is not posting , I have printed in the console , but I see `Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0` in Google chrome.

**But internet connection is good and stable.**

This is my vanilla javascript for posting data :

```
function onSignUp() {
  signupform
  var email = document.signupform.email_edt.value;
  var driver_rb = document.getElementById("driver_rb").checked;
  var password_edt = document.signupform.password_edt.value;
  var r_password_edt = document.signupform.r_password_edt.value;
  var url = 'https://tuvuge-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/signup';
  //var data = {username: 'example'};
  var data = {
    username: email,
    email: email,
    password: password_edt,
    isDriver: 'True'
  };

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
}
```

Then I attached the `onSignUp()` function to the button in html as below :

```
<form class="admin-modal-content" name="signupform" onSubmit="onSignUp();" action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>Sign Up</h4>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="email">
      <b>Email</b>
    </label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="you@example.com" id="email_edt" name="email_edt" required>
    <label for="email">
      <b>Select an Option</b>
    </label>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="driver_rb" value="driver" id="driver_rb">
      <label>Driver</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="passenger_rb" id="passenger_rb" value="passenger">
      <label>Passenger</label>
    </p>
    <label for="psw">
      <b>Password</b>
    </label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password_edt" name="password_edt" required>
    <label for="psw-repeat">
      <b>Repeat Password</b>
    </label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="r_password_edt" name="psw-r_password_edt" required>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

What am I missing ,because the endpoint has a message it brings when there's a success or failure of data posting , but I see the above message.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the javascript errors from the console. First line of the function is not valid syntax.

Comment: @astrocrack, could you please edit it for me , for more clarification?